# external javascript not working in ruby on rails

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I tried using

```
<%= javascript_include_tag "application" %>
```

and inserting my external javascript file in app/assets/javascripts/, but for some reason the effect that's supposed to be accomplished by this javascript file is not working. I suspected it was because I had previously installed coffeescript, so I uninstalled it by removing coffee-rails from my Gemfile and re-running bundle install. My app/assets/javascripts/application.js also has the

```
//= require_tree .
```

line in it.

I am also testing this locally, using rails server and then viewing it on localhost:3000.

Any ideas why it's not working?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: First things first: Are you sure the js isn't getting loaded? Load the  page in a browser and open the developer tools. From there you can check the resources that were loaded. If your js file isn't among them, then it's time to look for other causes.

Comment: Yup in developer tools I see that the following lines are present, and they link to the correct files:    <script src="/assets/jquery.js?body=1" type="text/javascript">   </script>
    <script src="/assets/jquery_ujs.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/custom_scripts.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script src="/assets/application.js?body=1" type="text/javascript"></script>

Comment: The comment in the `.js` file should be `//= require_tree .`/ Are you missing the `=` sign?

Comment: oops, no I'm not, I left it out of the post but it's in the application.js file. Thanks for pointing the mistake out..